# How to find &laquo; (&#171;) in a string

Tags: c#, regex

I need to find `&#171` in a string with a regex. How would you add that into the following:

```
String RegExPattern = @"^[0-9a-df-su-z]+\.\s&#171";
Regex PatternRegex = new Regex(RegExPattern);
return (PatternRegex.Match(Source).Value);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply use it directly:

```
var pattern = new Regex("&#171");
```

Of course, if used alone you can also use `String.IndexOf` instead. If you want to use it in another pattern, as in your question, go ahead. The usage is correct.

If, on the other hand, you *also* want to allow the named entity, use an alternation:

```
var pattern = new Regex("(?:&#171|&laquo;)");
```

Once again, the same can be done in a more complex expression. The `?:` at the beginning of the group isn’t necessary; it just prevents that a capture group will be created for this alternation.